# How to create a weighted composite covariance function using GPML toolbox in MATLAB?

Tags: covariance, matlab, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

I'm trying to create a composite covariance function to model my data. Specifically I want to create a kernel which is weighted between `@covSEard` & `@covRQard`. For ex: I want to give a 30% weight to `@covSEard` & 70% to `@covRQard`, something like `0.3*@covSEard + 0.7*@covRQard`

I tried the following options.

**Option 1 - Using the `@covSum` & `@covProd` functionalities**

`covFunc = {'covSum', {{'covProd', {'covConst','covSEard'}}, {'covProd', {'covConst','covRQard'}}}};`

Here, I'm trying to use the `@covConst` kernel which has only the signal variance hyper-parameter which I'm forcing to be equal to the weight (Ex: 0.3 for `@covSEard` & 0.7 for `@covRQard` in this case.
However, when I try to optimize the above kernel's hyper parameters, even the weights (which are actually the hyper parameters of the `@covConst` kernel are also getting modified.

**Option 2 - Using the `@covSum` functionality and repeating each kernel n times based on weight**

For example, if I want to give 1:2 weights to `@covSEard` & `@covRQard` respectively, I would do the following

`covfunc = {'covSum', {'covSEard' ,'covRQard', 'covRQard'}}`

However, in this case the number of hyper parameters would increase linearly and also I'm not sure if this is the right way to do things.

I want to know what is the correct way to create such a covariance function in GPML. Please suggest.